# Automatically center oversized images in divs

Tags: css, image, html, center

I'm trying to find a solution for the following trouble:

The content of the blog posts os my customer are going to be centralized on the page.

> |bbb|ccccccccc|bbb|

`b` is the body and `c` is the content

So I have a `2columns` div, after `8columns` div with the content and another `2columns` div (I'm using bootstrap);

> |2col|---8col---|2col|

My problem is that I want the images on the post which are bigger than the 8columns div to be horizontally centralized on the entire page.

> |2col|---8col---|2col|
>   |2col|cccccccc|2col| **c is the normal content**
>   |--############--|
>   |--############--| **# is the image**
>   |2col|---8col---|2col|

I **can't** put any element wrapping the `img` element;
I don't know the size of the image, because it shall happen to any image my insert on the post;

I searched for a lot of different solutions, but all of them work with the size of the image, using a 50% margin on the right and margin with half of the size of the image on the other side. On some solutions I need to wrap the image with another element and in my case it isn't interesting because it should be done on every image my customer publish.

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

## Edit

Here is my HTML:

`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="hiden-xs hiden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        {{ content }}
    </div>
    <div class="hiden-xs hiden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

`

What I'm saying is if I have an image on the "content" bigger than 8col, I want it to have it's original size, so `width:100%` doesn't work for me unfortunately :/

I also tried to use `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;` on the img, but it only works for images smaller than 8col. Any image bigger than 8col are automatically aligned to the left of the 8 col.

## Edit 2

What I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz4m1.png

What is happening:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3LuG.png

Comment: Could you provide some actual code of what you've tried so far? This code doesn't show any own research, nor does it show previous attempts. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for more tips on how to get a better chance of getting the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is my first time asking here. I provided my actual html and some print screens.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
img{ 
max-width:100%;
}
```

if needed
   and parent div of img add `**text-align:center**`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help, but I want the image to be bigger than its parent div. And `text-align:center` would make the text of the post to be centralised and I only want to centralise the images

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I trid to use the `margin auto` trick, but it didn't solve the problem because my image is bigger than the parent div. I also want the image to have its original size and not `100%`.

Comment: setting `max-width:100%` will take as much space as the parent element's `width` value. Setting `height:auto` will keep to aspect ratio proportions. This should work, check if you don't have a `float` or any margins/padding on image container

Comment: Thanks! Got it, but my image is bigger than the parent element and I want it. My image max-width should be the body width.

Comment: @JefersonBraun can you post a url to your file?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/x62nV/)**

**css**

```
body {
    margin: 0 150px;
}
.imageContainer {
    border: 1px solid #444;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.imageContainer > span {
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: -450px; /* -(width-container width)/2 */
}
.imageContainer > span > img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, what I need is exactly the images 120x100 and 280x100, without the `overflow:hidden`. The problem is that I'm using Jekyll and it uses Shopify markdown to create the posts, so it's problematic to put something like this `<span>
![image](/images.png)
</span>` on a .md file.